# Azure Websites + node.js - Cannot GET /

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service

When deploying a node.js / express app to Azure Websites I am getting "Cannot GET /" error in the browser. The same application runs flawlessly on the local machine.

`web.config` is standard (I only removed the Static Rewrite rule), so:

```
    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="src/server/app.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
```

Code is deployed in `src/server/` (node functions) and `src/client/` (static content) folders.

As per the FREB logs the src/server/apps.js is fetched, but in the end the following error is thrown:

```
ErrorCode   The system cannot find the file specified.     (0x80070002)
```

Inside `app.js` I have the following configuration for static files:

```
   app.use(express.static('./src/client/'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Websites runs node from the folder where the file defined in the `package json` as the start file is located, so e.g. for the following:

```
"start": "node src/server/app.js"
```

fact it will run `node app.js` from the `src/server` folder (you can find there also the `iisnode.yml` file). Which results in all relative paths getting messed up. One solution for this is to use absolute paths, so e.g.:

```
app.use(express.static('D:/home/site/wwwroot/src/client/'));
```

and switching between paths using e.g. `process.env.NODE_ENV` variable.

Comment: Another solution is to move startup script from src/server/ to wwwroot/ folder. This will require changes in just one file.